# foreach loop with 4 arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I need to use `for each` with 4 arrays for a school project but I couldn't find a solution somewhere. Is there a way to use `for each` loop using `4 arrays`.
I tried multiple things but nothing worked for me.

```
<?php
  $Voornamen = array( '0300013' => "Laurence" , '0266931' => "Peter" , '0267730' => "Pim" , '0279410' => "Arben" , '0297652' => "Robbin" , '0300838' => "Damian");
  $Achternamen = array( '0300013' => "Van der Wel" , '0266931' => "Kuipers" , '0267730' => "Hoomans" , '0279410' => "Hajrizaj" , '0297652' => "Visser" , '0300838' => "Trojak");
  $Woonplaatsen = array( '0300013' => "Enschede" , '0266931' => "Enschede" , '0267730' => "Enschede" , '0279410' => "Enschede" , '0297652' => "Overdinkel" , '0300838' => "Enschede");
  $Leeftijden = array( '0300013' => "17" , '0266931' => "20" , '0267730' => "20" , '0279410' => "19" , '0297652' => "16" , '0300838' => "16");

  $persoon = array_rand($voornaam, 1);

  foreach ($Voornamen as $Voornaam and $Achternamen as $Achternaam and $Woonplaatsen as $Woonplaats and $Leeftijden as $Leeftijd){
      echo "<table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            $Voornaam
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            $Achternaam
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            $Woonplaats
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            $Leeftijd
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>";
  }


?>
```

Comment: `foreach` can only take 1 array at a time. Is this the output you wanted or were you looking for a new table every loop? https://3v4l.org/6aJgV

Comment: What is the expected end result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the data structure would be a good solution but if you have to stick with that you can use this code

```
foreach ($Voornamen as $id => $value){

      echo "<table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            ".$value."
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            " . ($Achternamen[$id]) . "
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            ".($Woonplaatsen[$id])."
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            ".($Leeftijden[$id])."
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>";
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each of them one by one:

```
foreach($array1 as $key1 => $value1){
    foreach($array2 as $key2 => $value2){
        ... etc
```

But this can get rather messy rather quick. Do you really have to use 4 arrays?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your all your array into one array and create a function to show all the names here is the code:

```
$Voornamen = array( '0300013' => "Laurence" , '0266931' => "Peter" , '0267730' => "Pim" , '0279410' => "Arben" , '0297652' => "Robbin" , '0300838' => "Damian");
  $Achternamen = array( '0300013' => "Van der Wel" , '0266931' => "Kuipers" , '0267730' => "Hoomans" , '0279410' => "Hajrizaj" , '0297652' => "Visser" , '0300838' => "Trojak");
  $Woonplaatsen = array( '0300013' => "Enschede" , '0266931' => "Enschede" , '0267730' => "Enschede" , '0279410' => "Enschede" , '0297652' => "Overdinkel" , '0300838' => "Enschede");
  $Leeftijden = array( '0300013' => "17" , '0266931' => "20" , '0267730' => "20" , '0279410' => "19" , '0297652' => "16" , '0300838' => "16");

  //$persoon = array_rand($voornaam, 1);

  $arr = array($Voornamen,$Achternamen,$Woonplaatsen,$Leeftijden);
multi_array($arr);
function multi_array($array){
  foreach ($array as $key => $val){
      foreach($val as $v) {
        echo "<table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                $v
                </td>
            </tr>               
          </table>";
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to iterate on array; print the value and use the key with the [square brackets syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing) to access the corresponding values from the other arrays:

```
$Voornamen = array( '0300013' => "Laurence" , '0266931' => "Peter" , '0267730' => "Pim" , '0279410' => "Arben" , '0297652' => "Robbin" , '0300838' => "Damian");
$Achternamen = array( '0300013' => "Van der Wel" , '0266931' => "Kuipers" , '0267730' => "Hoomans" , '0279410' => "Hajrizaj" , '0297652' => "Visser" , '0300838' => "Trojak");
$Woonplaatsen = array( '0300013' => "Enschede" , '0266931' => "Enschede" , '0267730' => "Enschede" , '0279410' => "Enschede" , '0297652' => "Overdinkel" , '0300838' => "Enschede");
$Leeftijden = array( '0300013' => "17" , '0266931' => "20" , '0267730' => "20" , '0279410' => "19" , '0297652' => "16" , '0300838' => "16");

$persoon = array_rand($voornaam, 1);

foreach ($Voornamen as $id => $Voornaam) {
    $Achternaam = $Achternamen[$id];
    $Woonplaats = $Woonplaatsen[$id];
    $Leeftijd   = $Leeftijden[$id];
?>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo(htmlspecialchars($Voornaam)); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo(htmlspecialchars($Achternaam)); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo(htmlspecialchars($Woonplaats)); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo(htmlspecialchars($Leeftijd)); ?></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<?php } ?>
```

A better way is to keep all properties of the same person in a single [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and keep only only list that includes all the persons indexed by their IDs:

```
$persons = array(
    '0300013' => array(
        'voornaam'   => 'Laurence',
        'achternaam' => 'Van der Wel',
        'woonplaats' => 'Enschede',
        'leeftijd'   => '17',
    ),
    '0266931' => array(
        'voornaam'   => 'Peter',
        'achternaam' => 'Kuipers',
        'woonplaats' => 'Enschede',
        'leeftijd'   => '20',
    ),
    '0267730' => array(
        'voornaam'   => 'Pim',
        'achternaam' => 'Hoomans',
        'woonplaats' => 'Enschede',
        'leeftijd'   => '20',
    ),
    '0279410' => array(
        'voornaam'   => 'Arben',
        'achternaam' => 'Hajrizaj',
        'woonplaats' => 'Enschede',
        'leeftijd'   => '19',
    ),
    '0297652' => array(
        'voornaam'   => 'Robbin',
        'achternaam' => 'Visser',
        'woonplaats' => 'Overdinkel',
        'leeftijd'   => '16',
    ),
    '0300838' => array(
        'voornaam'   => 'Damian',
        'achternaam' => 'Trojak',
        'woonplaats' => 'Enschede',
        'leeftijd'   => '16',
    ),
);

foreach ($persons as $p) { ?>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo(htmlspecialchars($p['voornaam'])); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo(htmlspecialchars($p['achternaam'])); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo(htmlspecialchars($p['woonplaats'])); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo(htmlspecialchars($p['leeftijd'])); ?></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear of the final intent so I presumed the end goal was to display the data from the arrays in a table?

As mentioned you can only supply one array to `foreach` but you could, as the source arrays are of the same lengths, use a counter to allow access to other arrays.

```
$Voornamen = array( '0300013' => "Laurence" , '0266931' => "Peter" , '0267730' => "Pim" , '0279410' => "Arben" , '0297652' => "Robbin" , '0300838' => "Damian");
$Achternamen = array( '0300013' => "Van der Wel" , '0266931' => "Kuipers" , '0267730' => "Hoomans" , '0279410' => "Hajrizaj" , '0297652' => "Visser" , '0300838' => "Trojak");
$Woonplaatsen = array( '0300013' => "Enschede" , '0266931' => "Enschede" , '0267730' => "Enschede" , '0279410' => "Enschede" , '0297652' => "Overdinkel" , '0300838' => "Enschede");
$Leeftijden = array( '0300013' => "17" , '0266931' => "20" , '0267730' => "20" , '0279410' => "19" , '0297652' => "16" , '0300838' => "16");

$kv=array_keys( $Voornamen );
$ka=array_keys( $Achternamen );
$kw=array_keys( $Woonplaatsen );
$kl=array_keys( $Leeftijden );

$i=0;


echo "<table cellspacing='5px' cellpadding='10px' border='1'>";

foreach( $Voornamen as $key => $value ){

    echo "
    <tr>
        <td>{$key}:{$value}</td>
        <td>{$ka[ $i ]}:{$Achternamen[ $ka[ $i ] ]}</td>
        <td>{$kw[ $i ]}:{$Woonplaatsen[ $kw[ $i ] ]}</td>
        <td>{$kl[ $i ]}:{$Leeftijden[ $kl[ $i ] ]}</td>
    </tr>";

    $i++;
}

echo "</table>";
```

This outputs a table like this
[image: HTML Table]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible since all arrays have the same keys and size:

```
foreach ($Voornamen as $key => $value){
  echo $Voornamen[$key];// or just $value
  echo $Achternamen[$key];
  echo $Woonplaatsen[$key];
   echo $Leeftijden[$key];
}
```

Another way is to construct a multidimensional array from all the arrays and use two nested FOREACH loop.
............

My greetings to your teacher.